# export variable in shell script not working

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh, echo

I am trying to export few variables and invoke spark-submit using a shell script. However the export variables are not printing as expected. Please find below the code and help me in resolving the issue.

```
export BASE_LOCATION=/home/hduser/hdm
export EXT_LIB=$BASE_LOCATION/extlib
echo $EXT_LIB

export EXT_LIB_JARS=$EXT_LIB/common-csv-1.1.jar:$EXT_LIB/spark-csv_2.10-1.5.0.jar    
echo $EXT_LIB_JARS
```

I was expecting an output as `/home/hduser/hdm/extlib` from `echo $EXT_LIB`.

But I am receiving output as `/libe/hduser/hdm`

Also `echo $EXT_LIB_JARS` is not giving desired results.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Regards,
Adarsh K S

Comment: Missing `$` after `echo`. Please, copy-paste the real script you're using, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: Hi. I have $ after echo in my code. But it is not working. I missed to add it here.

Comment: It works for me. How do you **really** populate the variables?

Comment: Please separate the `export` statements from the assignments and run the script with `xtrace` on (`set -x`). Then share the output.

Comment: We need a [mcve] -- code we can copy-and-paste to see the same problem ourselves. As you can see at https://ideone.com/MVxRZR, the code you gave in the question does not demonstrate any problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the output you described when the BASE_LOCATION has `$'\r'` at the end (and `$EXT_LIB` apennds `/lib` to it, not `/extlib`).

```
#! /bin/bash
export BASE_LOCATION=/home/hduser/hdm$'\r'
export EXT_LIB=$BASE_LOCATION/lib
echo $EXT_LIB
```

Maybe you edited the script on MSWin and it inserted its line-endings into it? Or you extract the value from a file that comes from MSWin?

Just remove the `\r`'s from the value.

Comment: I do not have \r in the file. I am not sure why I am not getting the output

Comment: Try running `xxd` on the script source. Your editor might hide the `\r` from you, it's shown as `0d` in hex.

Comment: I ran cat <fileName> | od -c and saw '\r' in the file.Removed that and it worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: "thank you" = upvote/accept.

Comment: Next time, please post the actual script that doesn't work to make it easier for us to help you. I had to guess a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Probably the file you are editing is for a different user or you are not logged in as the user for the conf file you are editing.
If it is then i would hazard a guess that there are many more lines and it is set somewhere after in the conf script as something else or even dynamically held until restart by setting from an install script.

Comment: If a question doesn't provide enough details to do more than guess or hazard, its author should be encouraged to clarify it -- it's not yet ripe for answering. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, particularly the section "Answer Well-Asked Questions", particularly the bullet point regarding questions which "are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem" -- a question without a [mcve] very much has not identified a specific problem.